# Converting Varbinary into XML SQL Server With date pattern mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, type-conversion

I am trying to query my database for a delimited file that is saved as a `varbinary`. I am running the following query.

```
SELECT TOP 2 CAST('<![CDATA[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Content, 101) + ']]>' AS XML)
FROM FileTable WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CreatedBy = <userID>
ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC
```

Content of file looks something like this

```
04/10/2020|55555555|098765432109|Lorem Ipsum|44 lorem|04/10/2020 17:46|04/10/2020 18:31|22|Lorem Ipsum Text|Lorem, Ipsum|(111) 111-9999|TXT|Lorem Ipsum Text Test|Lorem Ipsum|Lorem|A1PH4NUM3|LoremIpsum|Lorem Ipsum Test, Lorem Ipsum Text|A22.2|
```

Some of the files convert fine while others turn into a blob of Chinese characters. The files that turn into Chinese characters have a date format that looks like this mm/dd/yy HH:mm. My hunch is that this format is what is causing the problem since I am using date_style as 101.

Can you advise me on how can I get around this problem?

Comment: If you don't need those records ..you can make use of Try_convert instead of convert if you are using SQLserver>= 2012 i think..it will convert it to XML format

Comment: Could some of the files be stored with U+FEFF [byte order marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in various combinations? e.g.: UTF-8, UTF-16 little endian, UTF-16 big endian, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the encoding when converting binary data to characters/string.

```
declare @filetable table
(
    id int,
    Content varbinary(max)
);

--insert unicode N'abc...
insert into @filetable(id, Content)
values(1, cast(N'abc nvarchar to binary' as varbinary(max)));

--binary (of unicode string) to unicode: convert(NVARCHAR(max)), works fine
SELECT CAST('<![CDATA[' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Content) + ']]>' AS XML)
FROM @filetable
where id = 1;

--insert ASCII: 'abc...
insert into @filetable(id, Content)
values(2, cast('abc varchar to binary' as varbinary(max)));

--binary of ascii to ascii:convert(VARCHAR(max)), works fine 
SELECT CAST('<![CDATA[' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Content) + ']]>' AS XML)
FROM @filetable
where id = 2;

--but not interchangeable
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Content) as toNvarchar, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Content) as tovarchar
FROM @filetable;


--**LATIN characters only**: in case only binary representations of ascii and/or unicode(utf16, ucs-2) strings are stored in Content..
SELECT  id,
    case when CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Content) = cast(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Content) as varchar(max))
    then CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Content) else cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), Content) as nvarchar(max)) 
    end  as nvarchar_string
FROM @filetable;
```

Comment: thanks! that was it, the files were saved in 2 different encodings *face palm*